# docker-compose issue: Permission denied when attempting to create/mount volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04, docker-volume

I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  dbs-poa-loc001d:
    image: percona
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_backup:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./create_databases:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    hostname: "dbs-poa-loc001d"
    container_name: dbs-poa-loc001d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - azion-network
...
```

When I try to create the dbs-poa-loc001d service (database for the project), I get the following error:

```
Starting dbs-poa-loc001d ... done
Attaching to dbs-poa-loc001d
dbs-poa-loc001d    | Initializing database
dbs-poa-loc001d    | mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
dbs-poa-loc001d    | 2019-01-11T01:17:52.060984Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
dbs-poa-loc001d    | 2019-01-11T01:17:52.062286Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory exists and is not writable. Aborting.
dbs-poa-loc001d    | 2019-01-11T01:17:52.062299Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
dbs-poa-loc001d    | 
dbs-poa-loc001d exited with code 1
```

This error doesn't happen on my MacOS computer at my job, but in my home computer (running Ubuntu 16.04) it does. I do noticed the `mysql_backup` folder on the host created to hold the volume data is set to group AND user root. Can anybody tell me what is going on, and how do I fix this? Already tried without success:

- Running docker-compose commands using sudo
- Manually changing the owner and user of the folder to my actual (low privileged) user.

My current setup and installed versions are:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
- docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad0
- docker-compose was installed using `sudo pip install docker-compose`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try to set permissions of `mysql_backup` to 1001:0?
something like `sudo chown -R 1001:0 ./mysql_backup`
or as an alternative but **only if the folder is empty** `sudo chmod 777 ./mysql_backup`

regarding to percona Dockerfile mysql user id is 1001
https://github.com/percona/percona-docker/blob/master/percona-server.80/Dockerfile

Comment: Changing the owner to 1001:0 did not work. Adding the 777 permission did. Still is very weird that I had to add that. Anyone knows of any better solution?

Comment: when you able to run percona with 777 permissions, try to run `lsof ./mysql_backup` while percona ran, to see what user (or userId) have open files in this directory. It should be user under that percona running. After that, you will probably able to set owner properly and correct permissions back to normal.